# Terminology for polygons

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

As you may know term "polygon" might mean few different things 
and its meaning has to guessed from context.
By some reason I have to use few of these meaning in one place.

So I converge to the following convention:

Polygon is a cyclically ordered set of points.
Then I could define its *sides*;
I can say then if the polygon is *simple*;
for simple polygons I can define its *interior*.
And then I need a term for the *set formed by the union 
of the interior and all the sides of the polygon*.
(Maybe "body of the polygon" or "solid polygon"?)

Did you see a term for this used somewhere (I need a term different from "polygon")?

Comment: Often in computational geometry, "polygon" means the closed region $P$, your solid polygon, and the boundary is $\partial P$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, this is bad terminology, for me polygon is not a set, say in general  $\triangle ABC\not\cong \triangle BAC$ but for solid triangles (which are sets) we always have $\blacktriangle ABC\cong \blacktriangle BAC$.

Comment: I like your neologism "solid polygon." I have not seen that used before, but it seems appropriate.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I am afraid that "solid" might be associated with 3D, like "solid geometry".

Comment: closed polygonal region?

Comment: I would say "closed polygonal domain".

Comment: @FedorPetrov,@TomGoodwillie It should look like "something of the polygon", say "closed domain of polygon" or "closed region of polygon". But anyway did you see these terms used?

Comment: Another option would be to use "polygonal chain" or "polygonal curve" for what you're calling a "polygon", and "polygon" for the closed region.

Comment: @YoavKallus, I do not like it because it brakes one notion into parts; I want to have "polygon" which has sides, diagonals, boundary, interior exterior and say hull, but I do not want to name any of these parts by "polygon".

Comment: Polygon = Polygoference + Polygle :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?                                      .

Comment: Not bad. The only problem, I did not see it used in this context. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again, I think this is the best answer, although it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

[Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_(geometry)), or [underlying space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnderlyingSpace.html)?      .

Comment: Face is used in the inductive definition of polyhedron, it is a polyhedron of lower dimension, so it is not exactly set.

Comment: Well, the `underlying space` of the face is.

Comment: That is too long...

Answer (score 2):

How about "filled-in polygon" or "filled polygon". A little searching turned up such a term used in this link in some notes on computer graphics: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~icss571/filling/

Answer (score 0):

why not speak of the compact or open polygon(al region) when refering to the region defined by the edges and, speak of the boundary if the set of edges is meant?

Or one could clarify, whether a "polygon" shall be topologically equivalent to a circle or to a disk (either closed or open).